# ASP.NET MVC Displaying Column Length

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to use if/else statement to render my data. When the column length is greater than 30 characters I want to use `substring` function on this column and render shorter data with '...'. But it doesn't work

```
@if (item.BOOK_Title.Length >= 30)
{

    @{var display = item.BOOK_Title.Substring(0,30)+"...";}
    @Html.DisplayFor(modea => display)

}
else
    @Html.DisplayFor(modea => item.BOOK_Title)
```

Please help, I dont know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: You should provide what the HTML expected/actual output is or an error message. "Doesn't work" is too general for anyone to help you.

Comment: Expected a "{" but found a "@".  Block statements must be enclosed in "{" and "}".  You cannot use single-statement control-flow statements in CSHTML pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this better to use a Razor "Helper Function", see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx

Since you will likely use this in more than one place, this is a great use of them.

Comment: Or even better -- put the behavior in the model itself . . .

Comment: @WyattBarnett - I would consider this to be view functionality.  If you change the layout, then you might change the way this trims the string, so it should logically be a view consideration.

Comment: @MystereMan - fair point, though I think in many cases, especially for stuff like this, you are really creating a specific model for the view and it makes sense for stuff like string trimming to happen over there.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the braces for the else.

```
@if (item.BOOK_Title.Length >= 30)
{
    var display = item.BOOK_Title.Substring(0,30)+"...";
    <text>@display</text>
}
else
{
    <text>@Html.DisplayFor(modea => item.BOOK_Title)</text>
}
```

Comment: Now I have error: Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code.

Answer (score 0):

In razor, your blocks need to have braces:

```
@if (item.BOOK_Title.Length >= 30)
{
    var display = item.BOOK_Title.Substring(0,30)+"...";
    Html.DisplayFor(modea => display)
}
else
{
    Html.DisplayFor(modea => display)
}
```